# scala sbt test run setup and cleanup command once on multi project

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, integration

I know I can add setup and cleanup code in sbt for the test phase by modifying the testOptions, e.g.:

```
  val embedMongoTestSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup( () => createMongod()),
    testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup( () => destroyMongod())
  )
```

The problem I have is that this done on a per project basis and then done once for every project. So when I have a multi project set up, I fire up several databases in this case (which would work, but means I have to configure per project ports, etc.).

Is there a way within sbt that makes sure that certain steps are only run *once* per any test phase, no matter if it is for multi projects, one project or a single test case?

Only way I figure is to manage the concurrency myself in the setup and cleanup parts, so keep a global counter that checks if it is the first one started or last one torn down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on [sequencing tasks](http://eed3si9n.com/sequencing-tasks-with-sbt-sequential), which you might find it useful.

If you want to aggregate tests and make sure things are sequenced, one quick way of doing that is making a custom command. The following defines a command alias called `sts`:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)
lazy val specs2Core = "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "2.4.15"
val startTest = taskKey[Unit]("start test")
val stopTest = taskKey[Unit]("stop test")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(app, webapp).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(addCommandAlias("sts", ";startTest;test;stopTest"): _*).
  settings(
    startTest in ThisBuild := {
      println("starting server...")
      Thread.sleep(500)
    },
    stopTest in ThisBuild := {
      println("stopping server...")
      Thread.sleep(500)
    }
  )

lazy val app = (project in file("app")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies += specs2Core % Test
  )

lazy val webapp = (project in file("webapp")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies += specs2Core % Test
  )
```

You can substitute the implementation of `startTest in ThisBuild` and `stopTest in ThisBuild` as you like.
By defining these settings at the `ThisBuild` level, `sts` command should work at both the root level as well as at individual subproject level.

```
root> sts
starting server...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 13, 2015 5:20:58 PM
[info] HelloWorldSpec
....
[info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 13, 2015 5:20:59 PM
stopping server...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 13, 2015 5:20:59 PM 
root> project app
[info] Set current project to app
app> sts
starting server...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 13, 2015 5:21:15 PM
[info] HelloWorldSpec
....
[info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 13, 2015 5:21:16 PM
stopping server...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 13, 2015 5:21:16 PM
```